# Error if DBnull, ms-access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to SUM columns in access database, and it somewhat works.
`column5` and `column6` are dates. Lets say I have records with dates 15/11/2016, and another one with 19/11/2016. If I select 'OdDate' as 15/11/2016 and 'DoDate' as 19/11/2016 it works, it sums the records. The problems come when I select from 15/11/2016 to lets say... 20/11/2016, in this case, scalar returns records from 19/11/2016, it ignores the records in 15/11/2016. And If I select few days further, then it throws error dbnull.
I know why it throws dbnull error, what I want to know is, why does it ignore records with 15/11/2016 when I select from 15/11/2016 to 20/11/2016, why doesn't it throw dbnull error, there are no records with 20/11/2016 date. Instead it only returns the records in 19/11/2016.

```
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = ("Database\Baza-Original.accdb")

    Dim SqlQry1 As String = "SELECT SUM(Column2 + Column3 + Column4) FROM [Table] WHERE Column1 = @1 BETWEEN Column5 = @2 AND Column6 = @3"

    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(provider & dataFile)
        myconnection.Open()

        Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(SqlQry1, myconnection)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", CB.SelectedItem)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", OdDate.Value.Date)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", DoDate.Value.Date)

        If cmd1.ExecuteScalar() Then

            Dim field As Int32

            field = cmd1.ExecuteScalar()
            LBL.text = field

            myconnection.Close()
            MsgBox("msg1. ", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "successful")
        Else
            MsgBox("msg2. ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Unsuccessful!")
            Return
        End If

    End Using
```

Comment: The WHERE and BETWEEN elements look garbled.  shouldnt it be `WHERE Column1 = @1 AND SOMEDATECOL BETWEEN @2 AND @3` ? cols 5 and 6 are part of the SUM, so are they values or dates?

Comment: The WHERE column1 part is probably not needed, but Im not sure I know what you are doing. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/

Comment: column1 is the name of the record I'm trying to sum, there are records with different names in column1, I edited the column5 and 6, I was replacing my Cyrillic letters and made an honest mistake.

Comment: I'm summing column2, 3 and 4 where column1 is name, between dates 5 and 6

Comment: same question: is column 1 a date or a "name"

Comment: column1 is name. Select Sum(Column2 + Column3 + Column4) FROM TABLE WHERE Column1 = @1 BETWEEN Column5 = @2 AND Column6 = @3

Comment: that WHERE clause still makes no sense.  it is syntactically wrong because you are not telling it WHAT is to be BETWEEN this and that.  If col1 is supposed to be equal to @1 that's the end of it.  It will find that record if there is one.  I cant tell what you want to achieve with the BETWEEN part.  At least it needs an `AND` or `OR`

Comment: Lets say that in Column1 there are several records named Name1|Name2|Name3|Name1 each of these records have value in the other columns. I'd like to SELECT SUM (Column2 + Column3 + Column4) WHERE Column1 = Name1 BETWEEN this date, and that date. This should select both records named "Name1" and sum them.

Comment: Yes - but the syntax for your BETWEEN is garbled.  it should be much like in the first comment an hour ago: `WHERE col1 = @p1 AND dateColName BETWEEN @p2 AND @p3` col1 cant be a name and a date. even if it is you need the AND and specify WHICH column is to be between this and that date

Comment: This works in sql, but in vb.net it doesn't return the total sum, it only returns sum of 1 record named "Name1" and there are more records named "Name1"

Comment: be sure the date for both rows is in fact between those dates

Comment: it is, I manually inserted the records for testing purposes. There are 3 records named "Name1" each of them is with different date. From 18/11/2016, 19/11/2016 and the last one 20/11/2016, In my program I select, from 17/11/2016, to 21/11/2016, it only returns 1 record. The one at 18/11/2016 while it ignores the others

Comment: Oh, yeah! Thanks for the SQL correction it works now. I didn't do it properly earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the `BETWEEN` operator looks temptingly simple to use, you have to be careful with it. On top of that, comparing dates is done strictly mathematically as opposed to what we might regard as the way to do it in human.

Also, `AddWithValue` can give unexpected results and should never be used because it is not worth the effort to make code that lets it work - [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

```
SELECT SUM(Column2 + Column3 + Column4)
FROM [Table]
WHERE Column1 = @1
AND Column5 >= @2 AND Column6 < @3
```

and in the code to set the parameters:

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@3", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, .Value = OdDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1)})
```

Comment: there is an overload for `Add` that creates the param for you from the args: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Date).Value = someDTVar`  a bit less wordy which is what the attraction to `AddWithValue` seems to be about

Comment: @Plutonix That is true, but I find it easier to use the way which works every time and it keeps it consistent in appearance in code (if more parameters are needed, like precision or size).

Comment: This produces the same  result. It only sums 1 record named = @1 and ignores the rest...

Comment: Thanks for the code to avoid using addwithvalue, I made it work with the new sql query and using parameters.add !